# How can i monitor a log file not only from updated log but also from previous log?

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my script where i wanted to monitor my log file which is declared in config file.
It will read line by line and throw error message when the keyword is matched.

INPUT: access.log file

```
 #!/bin/sh
print all lines error1 error1
error1
error1
error1

error1
```

INPUT: config.sh

```
  #!/bin/sh
logFile=access.log

string1=error1

string2=error2

string3=error3

string4=error4
```

here is the main script for monitoring log.

```
#!/bin/sh
source config.sh

tail -fn0 $logFile | \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "$string1\|$string2\|$string3"
if [ "$line" == "$string1" ]
        then
        echo "Error was found: $string1"
        fi
done
```

OUTPUT(in debug mode):

```
    ./main.sh
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
5: source config.sh
22: logFile=access.log
44: string1=error1
66: string2=error2
88: string3=error3
110: string4=error4
7: tail -fn0 access.log
8: read line
```

after running main.sh if only update the access.log file it can fetch error by keyword.

```
echo error1 >>access.log
```

OUTPUT of main.sh:

```
9: grep 'error1\|error2\|error3'
9: echo error1
error1
12: '[' error1 == error1 ']'
14: echo 'Error was found: error1'
Error was found: error1
8: read line
```

Problem: This script can fetch error only if the log file is updated with keyword existed line. I wanted to fetch error from both updated and previous log. Is there any way to find out error from the previous log?

Comment: ambiguous question. need more examples for input/output/behavior.

Comment: @DudiBoy thanks for your reply . I have updated my problem details. Please let me know if need any further explanation.